# Kivy: Quality of images

Tags: python, kivy, image-quality

i have programmed a little a Kivy/Python-program that opens an image and displays it. But it can cleary be seen, that there is a drop in image quality [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUM3u.png), when compared to the original image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJIls.png). So i am wondering why this is the case. Is this normal with Kivy or do i need to change something in my code?

Code:

Kivy-file:

ImageExample:

```
<ImageExample>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Image:
        source: "images/zdf.png"
```

python-file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ImageExample(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Was the image scaled? Consider providing a [mcve], please! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Thank you for the advice. And no, it wasn't scaled.

Comment: Do i need to tag names, so you can see, that i responded? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Firstly, read [mcve]. That code you posted can't be used to reproduce what you see. Further, it seems rather obvious that the two images are not the same size.

Comment: Ok. This should be a minimal reproducible example now. So you think the quality drops because the image was scaled down by the container of the image? @UlrichEckhardt